# Create one subscription for multiple 'observable consumers'

Tags: angular, rxjs

To manager state there is this store service for users. In the store there is a 'select' method which maps to get the users id's:

```js
type User = { userId: number };

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class SomeService {
  activeUsers$ = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);

  selectUserIds = (): Observable<number[]> => {
    return this.activeUsers$
      .asObservable()
      .pipe(map((data) => data.map(({ userId }) => userId)));
  };
  // ...
}
```

In the component I am calling that method to see which user is active:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
  <div>
    <h1>See console output</h1>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let user of users">
      <div [ngClass]="{'active': (activeUserIds$ | async).includes(user.userId)}">
        {{ user.userName }}
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  activeUserIds$: Observable<number[]>;

  users = [
    { userId: 1, userName: "John" },
    { userId: 2, userName: "Fred" },
    { userId: 3, userName: "Alex" }
  ];

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activeUserIds$ = this.someService.selectUserIds().pipe(
      tap((data) => {
        console.log("data: ", data);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

But in the console the happens the amount of times it's called in the template (three times):

```
// console output:
// data: []
// data: []
// data: []
```

It seems superfluous to have it done three times. But I do want it to react to updates to the state.

My thoughts were that by creating the 'activeUserIds$' in the OnInit I would have *1* observable and use that multiple times. But instead it seems like it's subscribing multiple times.

What would be the way to only have 1 subscription?

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-bird-n7xips?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: `(activeUserIds$ | async).includes(user.userId)` this code is responsible for calling it 3 time , because your *ngFor is running 3 times and its is executing observable 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating three subscriptions when you use `async` inside `*ngFor`. It can't know that the `activeUserIds$ | async` will emit the same value every time you subscribe to it.

One solution could be using a local variable in template and subscribe to it just once with directives such as [`ngrxLet`](https://v9.ngrx.io/guide/component/let) from NgRx.

In vanilla Angular probably the easiest way (without [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-a-conditional-result-in-a-variable) and this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15280) is to append `shareReplay(1)` and `take(1)` to the chain so it gets completed immediately and won't subscribe to the source Observable:

```
this.activeUserIds$ = this.someService.selectUserIds().pipe(
  tap((data) => {
    console.log("data: ", data);
  }),
  shareReplay(1),
  take(1),
);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-woypne?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Ah I see. I was also thinking in the lines of subscribing to the selectUserIds using a property 'activeUserIds: string[]' instead of the observable. But it feels like it's interrupting the flow. Something with cold/hot observables? Your answer does not do that. Is that correct?

Comment: The take(1) seems to not allow any future updates. If I remove it then it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with cold/hot Observables. Cold/hot Observable is a matter of the source Observable that comes from `someService.selectUserIds()`. `shareReplay(1)` doesn't turn "cold" into "hot" Observables without any other config options.

Comment: `take(1)` is used to complete the chain immediately. If you don't want that I'd go with wrapping the block with `<ng-container *ngIf="(obs$ | async) as result">`